# Spring Boot Rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

i am practicing with spring boot for work with restful applications

I have set a @RestController and @Entity like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public class RestControllerCar {
    

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cars")
    public Iterable<Car> getCars() {
        return carRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String brand, model, color, registerNumber;
    private Integer year, price;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cars")
    private Set<Owner> owners;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String brand, String model, String color, String registerNumber, Integer year, Integer price) {
        super();
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.registerNumber = registerNumber;
        this.year = year;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getRegisterNumber() {
        return registerNumber;
    }

    public void setRegisterNumber(String registerNumber) {
        this.registerNumber = registerNumber;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Set<Owner> getOwner() {
        return owners;
    }

    public void setOwner(Set<Owner> owners) {
        this.owners = owners;
    }
```

when i use postman to http://localhost:8080/cardatabase/api/cars i get a list of Cars

but even if i go to http://localhost:8081/cardatabase/cars, with _embedded on the top

it`s normal?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Let me guess you included `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` as a dependency.

Comment: Yes, if i remove it,works only http://localhost:8080/cardatabase/api/cars

Answer (score 0):

Is your repository annotated @RestRepository?  The _embedded make me think to the kind of output given by a @RestRepository for an array.

@RestRepository auto create all endpoint. As @M.Deinum pointed out, with the data rest starter, if ou remove it , you only have your controller, and not the one generated by @RestRepository.

Two main choices here:

1. You dont annotate the Repository. Just an interface which implement JpaRepository<YourEntity, TypeOfYourID> and use your    controllers
2. You use only the auto created controllers by @RestRepository.

Or, you can install swagger2 on your project, so, accessing the docs on your browser, you will see all available endpoints, and it may be more clear for you.
With swagger you will also see what is the return type of the endpoint, the parameters etc..
Swagger is really easy to install in a project and to use. (dependencies, one annotation and it's good.. for basic usage).

Comment: Thanks! My repository Inteface have not Annotations, and extends CrudRepository. if i put @Repository on it, nothing change. The auto created controllers are present. Thanks